# Select a single column value and store it in variable oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to grab a particular column value a.id and store it into a variable v_id. Then use this value to pass into a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE v_id a.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT id  into v_id from a where a.name='test' and rownum <2 order by id desc;
Print v_id;
doSomething(v_id);
END;
/
```

I'm getting this error in Oracle SQL Developer:

> Error report: ORA-06550: line 3, column 7: PLS-00103: Encountered the
>   symbol "V_ID" when expecting one of the following:
>
> := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":=" was substituted for "V_ID" to
>   continue.
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use `rownum` and `order by` you *have* to put the order by in a sub-query. There is no other way to guarantee that you get the correct value.

It's also good practice to deal with the possibility that there may not be an `id` that matches your query. I've added an additional `begin... end;` block to deal with this.

```
declare
   v_id a.id%type;
begin

   begin
      select id into v_id 
        from ( select id
                 from a 
                 where name = 'test' 
                 order by id desc )
       where rownum < 2 
             ;
    exception when no_data_found then
      v_id := null;
    end;

   dbms_output.put_line(v_id);
   doSomething(v_id);

end;
/
```

As @raukh noted (whilst I was writing this!) the problem is `print`, which should be `dbms_output.put_line()`

Comment: Thanks for the extra robustness, you were first so you get the check mark I suppose :)

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
Print v_id;
```

is not valid. Probably you meant:

```
dbms_output.put_line(v_id);
```

? (Note that you may need to run

```
set serveroutput on;
```

beforehand in order for the above to have an effect.)

Answer (score 2):

`PRINT` isn't a valid PL/SQL command, so that's going to create a problem.  Perhaps you wanted

```
DECLARE 
  v_id a.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT id  
    into v_id 
    from (SELECT id 
            FROM a 
           where a.name='test' 
           order by id desc)
    where rownum < 2;
  dbms_output.put_line( v_id );
  doSomething(v_id);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, my head is elsewhere I guess. I could have sworn print was working earlier.