# Save value into a variable in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I have a query where i have to use the result of it multiple times. So instead of running the query multiple times i want to save the query value into a variable once and use it multiple times to accelerate the query speed.

for example:

Declare VAr = select M_DATE from TBT

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select a single column value and store it in variable oracle sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934605/select-a-single-column-value-and-store-it-in-variable-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this in an interactive client, the answer depends on the client.  For SQLPlus you could do this:

```
VARIABLE my_date VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) INTO :my_date FROM dual;
END;
/
PRINT my_date;

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date_column = TO_DATE( :my_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' );
```

Note that SQLPlus does not support a `DATE` type for its variables, so you need to convert to a string when storing then back to a date when using the value.  I recommend always using an explicit conversion and format string, simply to avoid unexpected results if the default format is not what you are expecting.

Within a PL/SQL block or procedure, it would be a little simpler:

```
DECLARE
  l_mydate  DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT sysdate INTO l_mydate FROM dual;

  SELECT whatever INTO l_whatever FROM my_table
    WHERE date_column = l_mydate;

  <etc...>
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the result of the query then you need to use a select ... into;

```
var v_storedate VARCHAR2(19);
exec select m_date into :v_storedate from tbt;
print v_storedate;
```

For an anonymous SQL block

```
begin
    select m_date
    into :v_storedate
    from tbt;
end;
/
```